# Counting Point Types in Multiple Buffer Area in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a dataset of several hundred sampling locations (currently in point form). For perspective, many of these locations are within a few hundred meters of each other. I also have a land use dataset (National Land Cover Database). That dataset was in raster form; however, I converted it into a clipped point set. There are 15 classifications for the land use points.

I need to create 500m, 1000m, and 1500m buffers around each of my sampling locations and then count the number of land use points of each type within those buffers for each location.

I tried the Summarize Nearby feature, but that only provided me with information on the land use types that consisted of the largest and smallest proportions of the areas around my sampling sites. I really need the count for all 15 land use types down the level of each sampling site.

Is there a tool that will allow me to do this i.e. a tool for just generating a table that I could use for other analyses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the multi-ring buffer and then use the "Intersect" tool to merge the points with these buffers.

Assuming the landuse classification field is called "Classification", the Distance field is called "Distance" and the unique identifier for your buffered sites is "PointID".

You can then run the "Dissolve" tool over this merged dataset. In the Dissolve tool there are "Statistics" fields. Dissolve on "PointID", "Classification" and "Distance" and use the "Count" statistic on the "Classification" field.

The output will be a feature containing the count of classes within each distance

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but: The easiest way would be using the Tabulate Intersection tool. Use the buffers as input zone features with the ID of the sampling locations as "zone field" and the land use data set as input class features with land use as class field.

Tabulate Intersection can handle point, line and polygon features as input classes and creates output depending on the type of feature used.