# Aggregating values at building level data and getting values for block group level and by building type

Tags: arcgis-desktop, aggregation, building

I have data for the building level. I have classified these buildings into 5 different types. I need to aggregate the values of each building type and get data at the block group level.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you expand on what your data looks like? Try the Dissolve Tool. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440667/counting-point-types-in-multiple-buffer-area-in-arcgis-pro/440670#440670

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap? What have you tried?